# How to highlight (blink) a html link superscript text with some blink functionaity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I want to `highlight` an html `link` with some `superscript` text "new" with a circle or star symbol surronded to it.(the "New" text in superscript). and i want it to be blinked to indicate the user that it's a `new` link so that a `user` gets attention about it.

html:

```
    <li><a href="/refer"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;Referrals&nbsp;<sup><span style="border-radius:30%; border:solid black 1px;padding:5px">New</span>
</sup></a></li>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this css for blink

```
.blink_me {
   animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {  
   50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Modify it to which type of style you want.